# Number validation inside Do While loop and if statements

Tags: java

```
package validation;
import java.util.*;
public class Validation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String regex = "^[a-zA-Z ]+$";
        String regex1 = "\\d[0123456789]";
        String Char;
        String Num;
        do {
            System.out.print("What Is Your Name:");
            Char = input.nextLine();

            if (Char.matches(regex))
                System.out.println("Welcome"+" "+Char);
            else if (Char.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("String field should not be Empty.");
            else if(!Char.matches(regex))
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid String!");
        } while(!Char.matches(regex));
        do {
            System.out.println("How Old Are you:");
            Num = input.nextLine();
            if (Num.matches(regex1))
                System.out.println("You Are"+" "+Num);
            else if (Num.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");     
            else if(!Num.matches(regex1))
                System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
        } while(!Num.matches(regex1));  
    }
}
```

What are you seeing right now above is a working code and I don't have problem with it. The thing that I want to ask is that what if I want to add another feature on my code, like once you've type number 18 below on the number input field it will give you this output:

```
"Your are uderage".
```

Comment: it should be a simple two step process 1. here you check for a valid number using regex, 2. now you compare it with 18 to check for underage

Comment: What @xenteros was trying to say is: don't use variable names that start in upper case, instead try `String name`, `String number`. You can check this [convenstions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) to learn more about the subject.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question. Also reading [mcve] might be helpful.

Comment: All I need is to add another conditional statement like if I entered a number from 18 below it then it should give me an output 
"You are underage".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify it there. User's who would see this topic later might not read the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of storing age in `String` you should store it in `int`. 
Second variable names should always start with the lowercase. It should be `num` instead of `Num`.

If you want to do it like you have done it in your code then you can do like this.

```
do {
        System.out.println("How Old Are you:");
        Num = input.nextLine();
        if (Num.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");
            break;       
        }
        else if (!Num.matches(regex1)){
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
            break;
        }
        else{
            if(Integer.parseInt(NUM)<18){
               System.out.println("Underage, exiting");                
               break;
            }
            else
               System.out.println("You Are"+" "+Num);
        }     
    }while(!Num.matches(regex1));
```

Code conventions java : [Code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: Your code will most likely result in a `NumberFormatException` as you try to parse the use input directly prior to validating it.

Comment: It works just like what I'm expecting. Thank you very much sir, you saved my day ^_^...

Comment: Thanks. If it was helpful to you can you accept my answer ?

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah have you tried the code with a non-numeric input?

Comment: @dpr I guess you haven't read the question properly. He is assigning age to string and then he wanted to check for the underage constraint.

Comment: Infact the code is asking for non-numeric input only.

Comment: @FallAndLearn `Please Enter A Valid Number!` doesn't look like "asking for non-numeric input" to me. If the user inputs a non-numeric string, you are passing this string without validation to `Integer.parseInt` which will result in a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @dpr when I enter none numeric then I get this error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3asd"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at validation.Validation.main(Validation.java:52)
C:\Users\IT Officer\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Should I add Try catch code to avoide the error?

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah I know, that's what I was pointing out. Try the code in my answer...

Comment: @FallAndLearn now I'm facing another issues like when I type none numeric input then it throws me and Exception error.

Comment: I am not understanding the fact that how can age be "3asd". The part of the question which I have answered is what the OP asked which is "I want to add another feature on my code, like once you've type number 18 below on the number input field it will give you this output:

"Your are uderage". "

Comment: I have answered on how one can convert string to int which was what exactly asked.

Comment: @dpr I think you are trying to make a simple solution hard.

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah Why you would have to insert "3asd@!qwe" as age ??

Comment: will that input which I made is to check whether the regex is still going to work or not because before we convert the "num" from string to parseInt then the validation code is working properly. if you can check my code above when you type alphanumeric on the number input then it will tell you to  "Please Enter A Valid Number!". would this mean that the "else if(!num.matches(regex1))" is no longer executed?

Comment: @dpr if you can share you thought about this then I will really appreciate it.

Comment: @HaiderAbdullah actually I don't understand your comment at all. Please take a look at the answer I provided. This code should work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly you simply could add another if-statement to your check:

```
...
do {
  System.out.println("How Old Are you:");
  Num = input.nextLine();  
  // input is numeric?
  if (Num.matches(regex1)) {
    if (Integer.valueOf(Num) >= 18) {
      System.out.println("You Are " + Num)
    } else {
      System.out.println("You are uderage")
    }
  } else if (Num.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");
  } else if(!Num.matches(regex1)) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
  }
} while(!Num.matches(regex1));
...
```

In general the comments regarding code convention in the other answer are of course correct.

You could additionally take a look at commonly used libraries such as [Apache Commons Lang (StringUtils)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). These help a lot to avoid common problems such as missing null checks or provide useful functioninalty such as a `isNumeric` check on strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple conditional statement to the ones you already have. I'm using `Integer.valueOf()` since you've defined `Num` as a `String`.

```
        if (Num.matches(regex1))
            System.out.println("You Are" + " " + Num);
        else if (Num.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");

        else if (!Num.matches(regex1))
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
        else if (Integer.valueOf(Num) < 18) {
            System.out.println("You Are" + " " + Num + "so you're underaged");
        }
```

Maybe you should just set the type of Num as an `int` and use `input.nextInt()` to read an integer value instead of a String.

Comment: This won't work as desired as the `regex1` checks for the use input to be numeric. As any input that is parseble by `Ìnteger.valueOf` is numeric of course, your last else-if-statement will never be executed.